# 20sec unresponsivness on home server

Tags: server, freeze

I'm running a little home home server (for the last 3 years), currently 20.04.02, with a few services: samba, pihole, openhab, qbitrorrent, etc.. nothing heavy. samba share is running on a mirror mdraid (3x3TB WD Red)

A few days ago, while playing a movie from samba share, the video freezes, lasts about 20s, than continues to play. It repeats on a random amount of minutes. If i'm using a putty remote connection to the server, the interface also freezes (cli does not refresh, then when it unfreezes, the typed commands appear). I have webmin running, dashboard stats are showing this:

[image: stats]

Quick SMART check does not show anything, I'm currently running smartmontools (long test) on all three disks.

ping also dies:
Reply from xxx: time<1ms
Reply from xxx: time<1ms
Reply from xxx: time<1ms
Request timed out.
Reply from xxx: time=2518ms
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from xxx: time<1ms
Reply from xxx: time<1ms

Any tips on what to check next?

Comment: May I suggest that the info in the comment is best added to the question.

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog around the time of a slowdown. Also investigate network and disk activity on your image 12:33-12:35. It eats all your bandwidth and clogs your disk. An ordinary ssh connection should not cause that much activity.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV.

Comment: @waltinator My educated guess is that memory is not an issue (16G installed - usage is 4%, swap is showing 0% used).

But I did find out that if I disable qbittorrent-nox service the freezes are gone. I' asking for help there now.